# Expression for the connection between RNA strands

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm searching for proper expressions that mean *connection of RNA strands*. 
Up to this time I came with *strands connection*, *strands conjunction*, and *strands ligation*.

Are my expressions proper, or do you know other expressions?

Comment: Can you try to use it in a sentence?

Comment: A few examples: RNA strands become connected / conjuncted / ligated and longer molecule is created. Two strands join with each other in ligation reaction. Strand might join with other one and create longer sequence. Conjunction of strands a and b give sequence c.

Answer (score 6):

Almost certainly **ligation** is the preferred term here; note that the enzymes that actually connect the strands are termed [ligases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligase), which immediately suggests the preferred word for the action they perform.   I would strongly lean away from *conjunction*, which suggests to me  a word more suited to the particular orientation two strands of RNA might have towards each other, and certainly doesn't immediately suggest the physical connection I think you're implying in your question.  *Connection* also seems a weak word to use, because it does not convey the aforementioned physical joining together of the strands of RNA; if one used it, it might be ambiguous whether the strands are actually ligated to each other or simply *associated* together in solution, through weak ionic bonding or some such.

Finally, as a word of advice, you shouldn't really seek a reply to this sort of question at an English language site; technical terms often morph from their intended meaning when they are first coined, to a more precise and different meaning later on as the science advances, so that one might be mislead if one tries to divine the technical usage from the meaning in ordinary language  -- the stuff this StackExchange specializes in.  (In just one example, the TCS site recently hosted a question about what they would might rename the method *dynamic programming* if they had a choice in the matter; debates like this often occur quite often in the mathematical sciences, subjects in which this forum has no expertise.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I do not ask for strictly technical terms like ligation, but for some expressions that might be appropriate in described context. I need to describe some process and using the same words over and over again does not look to nice. I'm afraid that when I use some synonyms I came up with something weird.

Comment: @Darqer If this is a scientific or technical paper, I'm pretty sure your readers will forgive repetitiveness in favor of impeccable precision. I can hardly think of an acceptable synonym in ordinary language that would work in biological parlance -- the main problem with the lot is that they do not describe exactly describe _where_ the connection between the strands is, as _ligate_ does perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The term *RNA recombination* might be what you are referring to.